# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied error when trying to read a directory

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

I have the following code to extract faces from a photograph. Now I want to extract it from a directory i.e. multiple files at once.
This should be very straight forward, like just changing the 'MultiPeople/Faces/IMG100' to just 'MultiPeople/Faces' i.e. the whole directory. But I keep coming up with the error below the code. I have done all the usual checks, like making sure the account is an administrator, making sure the file or directory isn't open at the same time, etc.

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition

path = r"C:\Users\Julio\Desktop\Face Extraction\Output\face"
image = face_recognition.load_image_file('MultiPeople/Faces')

face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))

face_counter = 0
for face_location in face_locations:
    top, right, bottom, left = face_location
    print("I found a face in image location Top: {}, Left: {}, Bottom: {}, Right: {}".format(top, left, bottom, right))

    face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
    pil_image.save(str(path) + str(face_counter) + ".jpg")
    face_counter += 1


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julio\PycharmProjects\test\Extract faces from photo.py", line 5, in <module>
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file('MultiPeople/Faces')
  File "C:\Users\Julio\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 86, in load_image_file
    im = PIL.Image.open(file)
  File "C:\Users\Julio\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'MultiPeople/Faces'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure if this is solve your problem, but `face_recognition.load_image_file()` made for load just one image and not the directory/multiple files. Check if the problem can be there!

Also may be [this example](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/benchmark.py) can help you, look at it.

Comment: hmm ok - does anyone know how to load a directory or multiple files instead?

Comment: You could load all files in directory in list like this: `from os import walk`
`mypath='/home/name/.../'`
`f = []`
`for (_, _, filenames) in walk(mypath):`
`f.extend(filenames)`
`break`
And then use the method from link above - iterate through them/

Comment: The only issue with this is that sometimes there may be 500+ files. In this case, would this work?

Comment: Why it shouldn't? List with length of 500 is not that big, plus you store not objects, but strings. Loop through 500 elements in this case may be a little slow, but you can optimise after you get it to work :)

Comment: And if your problem will be (or already) solved, please, close the question